# Resaltar una fecha específica en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, datepicker

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer que una fecha concreta quede resaltada en un controlador DatePicker en Android Studio?

Mi objetivo es que una vez cargue la actividad que contiene el DatePicker unas cuantas fechas estén ya resaltadas(Aquellas que contengan datos relevantes para el usuario), aunque no seleccionadas. ¿Alguna forma de conseguirlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo así busco, la forma de conseguir que haya fechas concretas con un puntito debajo, como si hubiera una tarea en esa fecha concreta, pero todos los tutoriales que he encontrado son para javascript, css o html, nada para Android.

(Editado)

Estoy intentando sacarlo por mi cuenta. Lo que he hecho es crearme un nuevo archivo php que me devuelva todas las fechas que tenga un usuario concreto, y luego recoger esos datos en un JSONArray como se muestra a continuación:

```
public void cogerFechas(){
    String username = i.getStringExtra("us_usuario");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("us_clave");

    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String fechaAux;
                for(int x=0; x<jsonArray.length(); x++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
                    fechaAux = jsonObject.getString("fecha");
                    arrayIntFechas = new ArrayList<>();
                    arrayIntFechas.add(separarFecha(fechaAux));
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
                builder.setMessage("Error de excepción en el array "+e.getLocalizedMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }
            if(!arrayIntFechas.isEmpty()){


            }else if(arrayIntFechas.isEmpty()){

            }
        }
    };
    FechasRequest fechasRequest = new FechasRequest(username, password, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Usuario.this);
    queue.add(fechasRequest);
}
```

Separo las fechas en enteros para que luego el calendario pueda reconocerlas (Dado que el componente DatePicker requiere de tres enteros para alterar el año, mes y día), pero aquí me he quedado, dado que no se qué hacer a continuación de que el array se halla rellenado con todas las fechas posibles. Mi lógica me dice que tendría que haber alguna forma de recorrer todos los días del calendario y resaltar las fechas que coincidan con las que he obtenido yo, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo conseguirlo.

Aquí el código del método separarFecha()

```
public int[] separarFecha(String fecha){
    String[] añoMesDia = fecha.split("-");
    String añoS = añoMesDia[0], mesS = añoMesDia[1], diaS = añoMesDia[2];
    int año = Integer.parseInt(añoS), mes = Integer.parseInt(mesS), dia = 
Integer.parseInt(diaS);
    int [] arrFecha = {año, mes, dia};
    return arrFecha;
}
```

Comment: Algo como esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114425/cambiar-el-color-del-d%C3%ADa-en-un-datepicker

Comment: Esa pregunta la hice yo mismo. No busco cambiar el color de todos los días, lo que busco es una forma de hacer que días concretos tengan un punto, una marca o algo distintivo de los demás, como se muestra en la imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el siguiente enlace se ve cómo hacer lo que pido, aunque no se pueda hacer con un componente DatePicker como quise yo en un principio.

[Marcar elementos en un calendario Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xs5406vApTo)