# marcar un dia especifico en un datePicker Android Studio

Tags: android

Lo que quiero es que el usuario seleccione un dia en el datePicker y se quede seleccionado, como si fuera un evento,por ejemplo. Me imagino que esta fecha tenga que guardarla en una bd para cargarla cada ves que abra mi apk, pero el problema es: ya obtenido las fechas como ubicarlas en mi datePicker.Gracias.
Tengo esto,donde tomo la fecha que el usuario escoja,y la guardo en una base de datos, el problema es despues q hago con las fechas para que queden marcadas en mi datePicker.
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

```
public  boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.MenuOpcion1) {
        showDatePickerDialog();

        return true;
    }
    if(id == R.id.MenuOpcion2) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
              final String selectedDate = twoDigits(day) + "/" + twoDigits(month+1) + "/" + year;
            //aqui depues lo que biene es guardar esta fecha en la base de datos
        }
    });
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
private String twoDigits(int n) {
    return (n<=9) ? ("0"+n) : String.valueOf(n);
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado, recuerda que es bueno agrega al menos un [mcve], revisa [ask].

Comment: A ver si entendi. Ya tienes la fecha pero ahora lo que quieres que al cargar se marque esa fecha por defecto?

Comment: si mira,busque quien tenia algo parecido y encontre https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117501/resaltar-una-fecha-espec%c3%adfica-en-android-studio pero la respuesta esta en youTube y no tengo acceso a el actualmente,preferiria verlo en codigo

Comment: pon tu código para ayudarte

Comment: eso es lo que quiero,tengo las fechas y quiero que cada ves que abra la ventana o el datePicker estas fechas se marquen